# Time complexity for an unusual 3 nested loop

Tags: time, complexity-theory

```
for i:=1 to n do
    for j=1 to i do
        for k:=1 to j do Mod A
```

*Known that O(Mod A) = constant M;*

I tried and this was the result: O[(1+2+..+i)*(1+2+....+n)*M]= O[(i^2+i)(n^2+n)/4 * M) = O(n^4) because the maximum of i value is n. I wonder if this explanation is true.

Comment: why did you tag C++? The complexity is language agnostic and the code you did post is not C++

Comment: [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+sum+sum+M%2C+k%3D1+to+j%2C+j%3D1+to+i%2C+i%3D1+to+n) is your friend.